# Undefined Reference when Compiling Kobuki ROS examples from source

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, ros

I have been trying to compile the kobuki_keyop example in ROS Indigo from source on Ubuntu 14.04, I basically wrote a simple cpp file like the following:

```
#include "/opt/ros/indigo/include/kobuki_keyop/include/keyop_core/keyop_core.hpp"  
using namespace keyop_core;
int main()
{
KeyOpCore keyy;
}
```

then I compiled with the following:

```
g++ test.cpp -L/opt/ros/indigo/lib/kobuki_keyop -o test
```

but it keeps giving me the same old holy grail of cpp errors:

```
/tmp/ccsh6f87.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `keyop_core::KeyOpCore::KeyOpCore()'  
test.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `keyop_core::KeyOpCore::~KeyOpCore()'
```

**Update:**

as was pointed out by @Danh, there are solutions in the following link:
[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)
however, my question is ROS related, I did not write the header files that might cause the problem, and I can't poke around all of the interlinked ones hoping to find a needle in the haystack, I was just hoping someone with background in ROS who had a similar problem might pick this up and point me to their solution.

Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I don't think so @Danh, while I did consider the library linking cause in my question, but my question is more ROS related than it is C++ related. notice that my source file is pretty small, non of the solutions pointed out in that duplicate work for it, and I can't go poking around all the linked header files written by the ROS developers/community. I was just hoping someone from that background would pick this question up and help me figure the problem out.

Comment: Only the path of library is specified in `g++ test.cpp -L/opt/ros/indigo/lib/kobuki_keyop -o test` . Where is the library specified for linking? Use can use `g++ -v` to see if the library having code for the `class KeyOpCore` is getting linked.